# getting filename count from multiple tables group by that file name

Tags: sql, filenames

I am trying to query the following in DB2. T28, T29 and T30 are table names. They have filename as a column which is in all tables. I have to find the count of filename in all three tables group by filename. Can you help?

Well, I am trying this in DB2.

I am looking for an output like this.

```
filename  T28COUNT   T29COUNT   T30COUNT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT filename, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t = 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) t28count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t = 29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) t29count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t = 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) t30count
  FROM
(
  SELECT 28 AS t, filename
    FROM t28
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 29 AS t, filename
    FROM t29
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 30 AS t, filename
    FROM t30
) q
 GROUP BY filename
 ORDER BY filename
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9624d/1)** demo for SQL Server, but I believe it should work pretty much the same for DB2.

Comment: Hi, I want to display the count of filenames in each table The coun t of the file name  F1 in T28, T29, T30 tables. The count of the file f2 in T28, T29 and T30 tables. T28 is just a table name.

Comment: @Rams Hi. That is **exactly** what the query in the answer does. Did you look at the sqlfiddle demo I've provided??? Did you try it on your system? It uses a conditional count over `union`'ed resultset from 3 of your tables. If you for some reason think it's not doing its job please elaborate on exactly why and give some sample data and desired outcome based on it.

Comment: Hi Peterm, The query does exactly what I needed. Thank you, it is perfect.